# NHibernate with mapping by code and a SQLite database: saving many-to-one parent-child entities, child gets a null foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, many-to-one, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

Variations of this question have been asked and answered *many* times and the answers have a lot of overlapping details.  I have tried so many different things suggested by these answers, but none of them have worked in my case.

I have a SQLite database with a parent table and a child table.  It's a really simple setup.  I'm using NHibernate 4.0.4 with mapping by code instead of fluent as [it was suggested to me that the former is newer and an improvement over the latter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192527/what-is-the-difference-between-nhibernate-mapping-bycode-conformist-classmapping/39194838#39194838).

**ENTITIES:**

```
public class BillingItem
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    // ... other properties
    public virtual ICollection<PaymentItem> PaymentItems { get; set; }

    public BillingItem()
    {
        PaymentItems = new List<PaymentItem>();
    }
}

public class PaymentItem
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual BillingItem OwningBillingItem { get; set; }
    // ... other properties
}
```

**BillingItem MAPPING:**

```
public class BillingItemMapping : ClassMapping<BillingItem> 
{
    public BillingItemMapping()
    {
        Table("BillingItems");
        Lazy(true);
        Id(x => x.ID, map => map.Generator(Generators.Identity));

        Set(x => x.PaymentItems, c =>
            {
                c.Key(k =>
                    {
                        k.Column("ID");
                        k.ForeignKey("BillingItemID");
                    });
                c.Inverse(true);
                c.Cascade(Cascade.None);
            },
            r => r.OneToMany(o => { }));

        Property(x => x.Name);
        // ... other properties
    }
}
```

**PaymentItem MAPPING:**

```
public class PaymentItemMapping  : ClassMapping<PaymentItem> 
{
    public PaymentItemMapping()
    {
        Table("PaymentItems");
        Lazy(true);
        Id(x => x.ID, map => map.Generator(Generators.Identity));

        ManyToOne(x => x.OwningBillingItem, m =>
            {
                m.Column("ID");
                m.Update(false);
                m.Insert(false);
                m.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                m.Fetch(FetchKind.Join);
                m.NotFound(NotFoundMode.Exception);
                m.Lazy(LazyRelation.Proxy);
                m.ForeignKey("BillingItemID");
            });

        Property(x => x.DueDate, map => map.NotNullable(true));
        // ... other properties.
    }
}
```

**REPOSITORY:**

```
public void Add(BillingItem toAdd)
{
    using (ISession session = Helpers.NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    using (ITransaction tran = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        session.Save(toAdd);

        foreach (var pi in toAdd.PaymentItems)
        {
            session.Save(pi);
        }

        tran.Commit();
    }
}
```

**BUSINESS LOGIC:**

```
var bi = new BillingItem()
{
    Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    // ... others..
};

var pi = new PaymentItem()
{
    OwningBillingItem = bi,
    DueDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3)
    // ... others..
};

bi.PaymentItems.Add(pi);
var repo = new Repository();
repo.Add(bi);
```

As suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10374069/2704659) (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18387218/2704659) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557849/2704659) and many, many others), I have made sure to set the `Inverse(true)` in my `Set` (child collection) in `BillingItemMapping`.  I have also set my bi-directional references in the `PaymentItem` object:

```
OwningBillingItem = bi
```

and `BillingItem` object:

```
bi.PaymentItems.Add(pi);
```

I feel I've setup everything else the way it should be, and I've tinkered around with a lot of the mapping settings based on suggestions from various other sources.  However, I just can't figure out why it's not working.

The problem is, I can't get the foreign key column on the `PaymentItem` record to hold the ID from the `BillingItem`.  If I set the column to not allow nulls (which is the way it should be), I get a null constraint exception.  If I set it to allow nulls (for testing), it just gets set to null (obviously).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hehe, there is something wrong with your `PaymentItemMapping` , the correct mapping should be like this:

```
public class PaymentItemMapping : ClassMapping<PaymentItem> {

    public PaymentItemMapping() {
        Table("PaymentItems");
        Lazy(true);
        Id(x => x.ID, map => map.Generator(Generators.Identity));

        ManyToOne(x => x.OwningBillingItem, m => {
            //Do not map to m.Column("ID");
            m.Column("BillingItemID");
            // BillingItemID can be insert and update
            m.Update(true);
            m.Insert(true);
            m.Cascade(Cascade.None);
            m.Fetch(FetchKind.Join);
            m.NotFound(NotFoundMode.Exception);
            m.Lazy(LazyRelation.Proxy);
            m.ForeignKey("BillingItemID");
        });

        Property(x => x.DueDate, map => map.NotNullable(true));
        // ... other properties.
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One part of the mapping, which seems to be wrong, is a `column` of a **`set`**

```
// BillingItemMapping()
Set(x => x.PaymentItems, c =>
{
    // this should refer to column where parent id will be found
    c.Key(k =>
    {
        k.Column("ID");
        k.ForeignKey("BillingItemID");
    });
```

so it should be

```
    c.Key(k =>
    {
        k.Column("BillingItemID");
    });
```

*Foreign Key is just for sql generators.. it could be skipped now*

Also, for every collection I use cascading

```
Set(x => x.PaymentItems, c =>
{
    c.Key(k =>
    {
        k.Column("BillingItemID");
    });
    c.Inverse(true);
    //c.Cascade(Cascade.None);
    c.Cascade(Cascade.All);
},
```

With that in place, we can simplify call to persist that all

```
using (ISession session = Helpers.NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
using (ITransaction tran = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    session.Save(toAdd);

    //foreach (var pi in toAdd.PaymentItems)
    //{
    //    session.Save(pi);
    //}

    tran.Commit();
}
```

*(we still need to keep both references parent-child / child-parent)*

And finally - when we have cascade in place - we MUST allow NHibernate to do its job - to INSERT and UPDATE that relation

```
ManyToOne(x => x.OwningBillingItem, m =>
{
    m.Column("ID");
    // this is stopper - DO NOT use it
    //m.Update(false);
    //m.Insert(false);
```

So, do not set *`Update(false)`* and *`Insert(false)`* if we want to be Updated and Inserted. That should solve that all..

This could also get some insight:

#### [Minimal and correct way to map one-to-many with NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29985158/1679310)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I just tried that, and it didn't make a difference.  Same exact results.

Comment: Column must match the other table column. So, we do have a progress. I will try to observe more

Comment: Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Another part, which I would suggest to change... is to use cascade. We then have to assign both sides, but only parent can be saved

Comment: Yes. We always should work the way.. that parent is persisted `session.Save(parent)` and the rest is driven by NHibernate. Why? we can **be sure, that parent is stored sooner enough, than a child - to already have a key**. So, with these two changes I guess it should work

Comment: Okay I modified it based on your update (with cascade on the parent side), but got the same result.  This time it occurred on saving the parent whereas before it was inside the loop, on saving the child.

Comment: So, I found another issue ;) Hope now you should have it working. Good luck with NHibernate

Comment: I commented out everything below `m.Column("ID");` in the many-to-one, but, alas, same issue.

Comment: This way I doubt I could do more. Check my link, to see what I really do use for mapping. The real minimum. Next is to be sure, that both sides of relation are set. The rest is up to NHibernate. Sorry I cannot help here more ;(

Comment: Well I truly appreciate your time anyway.  Thanks again.